# Spring boot - Independant scheduled tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I work with Java 8.
I have about 20 scheduled tasks (so about 20 java class) that execute different process with pdf files. Each task has is own frequency. The frequencies are stored in database. So I can change frequency in database and I don't have to restart my tomcat. This is one of them :

```
@Service
public class InboundJob implements SchedulingConfigurer {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InboundJob.class);

@Autowired
InboundService inboundService;

ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar;

@Override
public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
    if (scheduledTaskRegistrar == null) {
        scheduledTaskRegistrar = taskRegistrar;
    }
    if (taskRegistrar.getScheduler() == null) {
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(inboundService.poolScheduler());
    }

    taskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(
        () -> scheduleCron(inboundService.getJobRepo().findByLibelleIgnoreCase("INBOUND").getFrequency()),
        t -> {
            CronTrigger crontrigger = new CronTrigger(inboundService.getJobRepo().findByLibelleIgnoreCase("INBOUND").getFrequency());
            return crontrigger.nextExecutionTime(t);
            }
        );
}

public void scheduleCron(String cron) {
    
    try {
        Job inboundJob = inboundService.getJobRepo().findByLibelleIgnoreCase("INBOUND");
        if (inboundJob.getStatus() == null) {
            for (Bannette item : inboundService.getBannetteRepo().findByIdaijobAndStatus(inboundJob.getIdaijob(), null)) {
                if (!inboundService.isFolderExisting(item.getFolderpath())) {
                    logger.error("InboundJob - Le répertoire {} n'existe pas ", item.getFolderpath());
                } else {
                    ArrayList<File> filesList = inboundService.getFileList(item.getFolderpath());
                    if (filesList.size() > 0) {
                        logger.info("InboundJob: " + filesList.size() + " nouveau(x) fichier(s) dans " + item.getFolderpath());
                        inboundService.trtList(filesList, item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ure) {
        logger.info("InboundJob - ERROR: " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ure));
    }
}

public void activateScheduler() {
    logger.info("Re-Activating Scheduler");
    configureTasks(scheduledTaskRegistrar);
}

}
```

The problem is, if a task runs, the others can't start until it has finished...
Is there a way to make them independant ?

------ edit 2022/04/14 -----
this is additionnal info asked in comment
I use spring boot
the imports in my class are

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfigurer;
import org.springframework.scheduling.config.ScheduledTaskRegistrar;
import org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.test.mc.entity.Bannette;
import com.test.mc.entity.Job;
import com.test.mc.job.service.InboundService;
```

and poolScheduler method in my custom InboundService class

```
 @Bean
public TaskScheduler poolScheduler() {
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("ThreadPoolTaskScheduler");
    scheduler.setPoolSize(1);
    scheduler.initialize();
    return scheduler;
}
```

The aim of this mecanism is to get information about frequency in database. And if I change the frequency in my table, the new value is effective without to restart tomcat server. It works fine !

Finally, this is the main method of the project with spring boot configuration

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class MyKlinckApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer  {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyKlinckApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(MyKlinckApplication.class);
}
```

}

tell me if you need more

Comment: probably the problem lies outside the code you posted. What does ScheduledTaskRegistrar do? I don't know it and it doesn't show up in the JDK javadoc. Probably you/we need to look at its code to do find out what is going on.

Comment: Where do the `@Service` & `@Autowired` annotations come from? Add mentions and tags for relevant frameworks.